# Python - regex with URLs

Tags: python, regex

why regex do not match URLs? what is wrong with this example?

```
import re

link = "http://example.com/~abc/cgi-bin/abc/"
regex = r'[c][g][i]'

matchOBJ = re.match(regex, link)

if (matchOBJ):
    print "GOT IT"

print "END"
```

Comment: Because `match` checks the start of the string - try `re.search`. Also, note that you can just do `if 'cgi' in link:`, regex is completely pointless here.

Comment: re.search make it. THX!

Answer (score 0):

**[c][g][i]** doesn't really make sense as a regular expression.
You probably want just "cgi".

Perhaps you meant "[cgi]"? But then you'd be matching "either c or g or i".

For example, [cgi].*

will match

- **c**ats
- **g**oats
- **i**guanas
- **g**

[cgi] will happen to match "cgi" because of the beginning 'c'.

You probably want something close to:

```
import re

link = "http://example.com/~abc/cgi-bin/abc/"
regex = r'.*\/cgi-bin\/.*'

matchOBJ = re.match(regex, link)

if (matchOBJ):
    print "GOT IT"

print "END"
```

But consider just

```
 if "cgi-bin" in link:
    print "GOT IT EASY"
```

Comment: That's even *more* overcomplicated!

Comment: Just answering the question as stated